# reading line by line and storing in an array of structure

Tags: c

I'm trying to read lines from a text file line by line and store it in an array. the txt file has some question in it which will be asked to the player !

Here's some of the questions !!

```
1: När kom potatisen till Europa?;A:1300-talet; B:1500-talet; C:900-talet;D:1700-talet\n
rätt svar : B

2: I vilken enhet mats elektrisk spänning ?;A:Ampere;B:Volt;C:Joule;D:Watt\n
Rätt svar: A

3: Från vilket land har vi fått lego?;A:Tyskland;B:Australien;C:Japan;D:Danmark\n
rätt svar : D
```

Its in Sweden !

I have made a function that splits the line wherever it finds a semicolon! like this:

```
void readline_andsplit()
{
    char str[500];
    char *ptr;// token
    FILE * fp = fopen("gameee.txt","r");

   while(fgets(str, 500, fp)){            // read 500 characters
                  // print what we read for fun
    ptr = strtok(str, ";");         // split our findings around the " "

    while(ptr != NULL)  // while there's more to the string
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);     // print what we got
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); // and keep splitting
    }

   }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

And here's the main code:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int numProgs = 0;
    char* nrofqeustions[50];
    char line[80];
    int j = 0;
    char correctanswer;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("gameee.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {
        nrofqeustions[i] = calloc(strlen(line)+1, 1);   //add each filename into array of nrofqeustions
        strcpy(nrofqeustions[i], line);
        i++;  //count number of nrofqeustions in file
    }

    //check to be sure going into array correctly
    //for (j=0 ; j<numProgs+1; j++) {
    //printf("\n%s", nrofqeustions[j]);
    //}

    printf("%s\n",nrofqeustions[0]);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to produce the following output:

```
1: När kom potatisen till Europa?
A:1300-talet
 B:1500-talet 
C:900-talet
D:1700-talet
```

When the user chooses it moves on to the next question ! it's a quiz 
i'm kinda of new to the language !

Here's my struct :

```
 struct quiz{
char question[x];
char alt [4];
char correctanswer[1];


};
```

Comment: I cant see where you are calling the function from `main()`

Comment: i've tried but when im calling it it prints out all the questions at once ! i forgot to mention that im going to be using a structure were all my question as well as the answers will be stored !

Comment: ook, so you want it to print the question, ask for the answer by the user, and then move on to next question? And where is this structure in which you want to store your questions and answers

Comment: What I am getting out of this question is : Store the first question along with its options in a string and then print the Question and Options as desired output is stated... Is that so?

Comment: exactly!! i've edit  it now !

Comment: yea exactly! @nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

To store the question along with the right answer you would need a structure something like this

```
struct quiz 
{ 
    char question[50];
    char* alt[4];
    char correctanswer[1];
};
```

Then in the `while` loop you can read the question and store in the structure

```
struct quiz all_ques[10];
int i = 0;


//use i to terminate the loop, as how many questions are there in the file
while(fgets(str, 500, fp) || i<4)               // read 500 characters
{
    ptr = strtok(str, ";");           // split our findings around the " "
    strcpy(all_ques[i].questions, ptr);    // store the question

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");            // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[0] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[0], ptr);    // store the first option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[1] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[1], ptr);    // store the second option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[2] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[2], ptr);    // store the third option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[3] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[3], ptr);    // store the fourth option

    fgets(str, 500, fp)
    strcpy(all_ques[i].correctanswer, str);    // store the correct answer

    i++;
}
```

---

After this you can use the array of structure `all_ques[]` to give the questions to the users.

Comment: thank u @Haris  for ur time !! but i still get some errors when i run the program !!

Comment: @HaidarWahid, Make an edit in your question and add the new code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



struct quiz
{
    char questions[50];
    char* alt[4];
    char correctanswer[1];
};

int main (){

struct quiz all_ques[10];
int i = 0;

FILE *haidar;
haidar=fopen("gameee.txt","r");
char str[500];
char *ptr;

while(fgets(str, 500, haidar))               // read 500 characters
{
    ptr = strtok(str, ";");           // split our findings around the " "
    strcpy(all_ques[i].questions, ptr);    // store the question

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");            // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[0] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[0], ptr);    // store the first option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[1] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[1], ptr);    // store the second option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[2] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[2], ptr);    // store the third option

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");       // and keep splitting
    all_ques[i].alt[3] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].alt[3], ptr);    // store the fourth option

    fgets(str, 500, haidar);
    strcpy(all_ques[i].correctanswer, str);    // store the correct answer

    i++;
}
}
```

sorry if i did some dummy mistakes!! really new and trying to learn @Haris